# Getting data from different tables between dates when each table has it on date modified

Tags: oracle, join

Like to get some views from you all, regarding one scenario i'm struggling with currently. Below is a problem statement

I have Table A , B , C

A has below column
user|modified date| wokred_on A | ..some more related to user operation

B has columns
user | modified date |  worked on B | ..some other columns

C has columsn
user | modified date | worked on C| ..some other columns

these tables are not have any direct relation except then user.

we have to pull data from these tables for a user between given dates with the count op action or work he has done between a given date range?

my struggle here is these each table has it's own date modified if a date range selected which is not in other column but still i need to pull the data as user has worked on it in between dates.

can it be possible to select these dates and have the in one column so that one can put that in where clause and having outer joins to pull other records ?

Sorry for this big problem statement. any suggestions are very much appreciated

Below is a use case.just extending the assumption given by littlefoot

First, test case:

```
SQL> create table a (cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date,action );
```

varchar2 (10) )
    Table created.

```
SQL> create table b (
Table created.cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date,action
```

varchar2 (10) );

```
SQL> create table c (cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date,action
```

varchar2 (10) ));

```
Table created.

SQL> insert into a values ('lf', date '2018-05-01', 'issue raised');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into a values ('mc', date '2018-05-01', 'issue raised ');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into b values ('lf', date '2018-05-01',issue raised');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into b values ('lf', date '2018-05-01','issue resolved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('if', date '2018-05-28',' issue resolved');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('mc', date '2018-05-13','issue raised');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('mc', date '2018-05-13','issue resolved');

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from a;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D. ACTION 
---------- ----------
lf         2018-05-01     issue raised
mc         2018-05-01    issue raised

SQL> select * from b;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D    ACTION
---------- ----------.         ______________
lf         2018-05-01    issue raised
lf         2018-05-01.  issue resolve 

SQL> select * from c;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D. ACTION
---------- ----------
If         2018-05-28.      issue resolve
mc         2018-05-13.    issue raised
mc         2018-05-13.    issue resolve

CUSER    DATE             CNT_ISSUE_RAISED   CNT_ISSUE_RESOLVED
```

------  -------           ---------------   -------------------
    if   2018-05-01             2                   1
    lf   2018-05-28             0                   1
    mc   2018-05-01             0                   1
    mc   2018-05-13             1                   1

Comment: Can you give example data and the results you are hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

First, test case:

```
SQL> create table a (cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date);

Table created.

SQL> create table b (cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date);

Table created.

SQL> create table c (cuser varchar2(10), modified_date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into a values ('lf', date '2018-05-01');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into a values ('mc', date '2018-05-15');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into b values ('lf', date '2018-05-07');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into b values ('lf', date '2018-05-08');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('jw', date '2018-05-28');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('mc', date '2018-05-13');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into c values ('mc', date '2018-05-22');

1 row created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from a;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D
---------- ----------
lf         2018-05-01
mc         2018-05-15

SQL> select * from b;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D
---------- ----------
lf         2018-05-07
lf         2018-05-08

SQL> select * from c;

CUSER      MODIFIED_D
---------- ----------
jw         2018-05-28
mc         2018-05-13
mc         2018-05-22
```

Query which returns desired result - number of rows per each user in every table, in desired date period. As I use SQL*Plus, variables are preceded by `&&` to avoid multiple insert requests. In a tool you use, that might be a colon (`:`).

```
SQL> select nvl(nvl(a.cuser, b.cuser), c.cuser) cuser,
  2         count(distinct a.modified_date) cnt_a,
  3         count(distinct b.modified_date) cnt_b,
  4         count(distinct c.modified_date) cnt_c
  5  from a full outer join b on a.cuser = b.cuser
  6         full outer join c on a.cuser = c.cuser
  7  where a.modified_date between &&date_from and &&date_to
  8     or b.modified_date between &&date_from and &&date_to
  9     or c.modified_date between &&date_from and &&date_to
 10  group by nvl(nvl(a.cuser, b.cuser), c.cuser)
 11  order by 1;
Enter value for date_from: '2018-05-01'
Enter value for date_to: '2018-06-01'

CUSER           CNT_A      CNT_B      CNT_C
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
jw                  0          0          1
lf                  1          2          0
mc                  1          0          2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Little foot. I updated your assumption with which i'm expecting.  Your assumption was very much near about what is needed here is the date and the count of action performed by each user. Hope this help. Sorry for my only descriptive question .

Comment: You're welcome. Huh, I've just rejected "someone's" edit - it seems it was yours. Anyway: if you managed to get the solution, you can post it as "answer" as well. Or, edit the question and provide new information.